# Sitecore 8 : Component locking issue

Tags: locking, sitecore, roles, sitecore7, sitecore8

I was trying to do some deep dive into locking mechanisms in Sitecore 8 and found out something strange. I have created a role "CA" that has access to both Content Editor and Exp Editor. Then I created two users: user1 and user2.

Now, I created a page "gridtest" as a test page which has a grid component. I logged in as user1 into content editor and locked the grid component in the gridtest page. Then i logged in as user2 into experience editor and locked the page "gridtest". As a result, user2 was able to add/delete component from the grid which was locked by user1.

[image]

Also, I logged in as user1 into content editor to see if the grid component was still locked and yes, it was locked by user1. How am i getting this behavior ?

Is this sitecore's behavior that is holds page level lock superior to component lock ?

All help/suggestions appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by locking the grid component? Have you locked datasource of the grid component? Or the component definition item under `Layout`?

Comment: First, I created the page gridtest and then created the grid component.Then, as user1 I have locked the datasource of the grid in the content editor.

Answer (score 3):

Sitecore does not allow you to lock a component. The only thing you can lock is an **item**.

What does it mean that you locked an item? It means that other users can not edit this particular item (except from the admin users).

In your scenario, you locked a datasource item of a component as **User1** and you locked a page which has that component as **User2**. Now when you try to add/remove another component from that grid component as **User2**, you're not changing the datasource item, you're changing the page item. That's why **User2** can do this.

**User2** in this scenario will not be able to edit fields of the datasource item (cause it's locked by **User1**).

**User1** in this scenario will not be able to change the page with the component (cause it's locked by **User2**).

Comment: However, User2 is allowed to add/delete the components from the grid locked by User1.

Comment: No. Grid is not locked. It's the datasource of the grid which is locked. You can not lock component.

Comment: If the data source is locked then sitecore should not allow user2 to make any changes to that component right ?

Comment: No. It only means that other users cannot do any changes to the datasource item.

Comment: In my case user2 has full rights and can add content to the grid and i dont get it how to stop user2 from doing this. What i thought was page lock is superior than the datasource lock.

Comment: That's what I meant in the first sentence of my answer. You **cannot** achieve this. Sitecore does not have a mechanism for locking components.